# PG_upgrade with Rsync 9.6 to 13 on Standby Server - Postgres password prompt issue

Tags: postgresql

I am utilising the pg_upgrade documentation for 9.6 to 13. I can upgrade from 9.6 to 13 with the --link issue without issue on the master server. I have a slave machine which I want to upgrade, instead rebuilding the slave (which will take considerable amount of time) I want to utilise the rsync which is documented in pg_upgrade documentation.

The servers both have the postgres software followed by the custom shared objects etc.

When running rsync it is prompting for the postgres password.

rsync --archive --delete --hard-links --size-only --no-inc-recursive --dry-run /var/lib/pgsql/9.6 /var/lib/pgsql/13 remoteserverIP:/var/lib/pgsql/13 --dry-run

I do not know the postgres password, however I could reset the postgres password within a psql window on the slave machine, is there anyway of bypassing this?

Any help is much apprecaited.

Comment: It is asking for the password of the OS account 'postgres', which is not something you can change with psql.  You can do the rsync as root instead, if you don't want to assign a password for 'postgres'.

Comment: @jjanes when doing as root it still asks me for root password, which I also dont know....

Comment: How did you pg_upgrade master in the first place?  You need to get file-level access somehow to do that.

Comment: @jjanes I did pg_upgrade on the master logged into the master, when I go to do rsync against the slave machine as root user requests password for remote root user I assume.

Comment: Sorry, should have asked how you set up replication in the first place.  You need an OS account you can log on to on the replica to do that, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up SSH keys that allow you to connect to the other machine without a password:

On the primary, become user `postgres` and run

```bash
ssh-keygen
```

to create an ssh key without password.

Then add the public key generated in `~postgres/.ssh` to `~postgres/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the standby server.

Now user `postgres` on the primary should be able to ssh to the standby without a password. Then `rsync` should work without a password as well.

Comment: Thanks @laurenz-albe that did the trick.